# How can I get current values for a ManyToManyField in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Model I have a `ManyToManyField` over a different Model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    field = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Assuming I have `field` poblated with some values, I'm trying to get a list of the items that the user unselected before hitting the `Save` button. For that, I've overloaded the `save()` method inside `B`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    print self.field.all()
```

However, when hitting the `Save` button, the values of `self.field.all()` I get are the ones that I had when I loaded the form.

For example, if I had two selected items in the list (`a` and `b`) and I unselect `b` and hit the `Save` button, `self.field.all()` at `save()` time is still `a` and `b`. If I edit the item again, I see `b` is unselected, I select it back and at `save()` time `self.field.all()` is only `a`.

My assumption is that unselected items are processed after the `save()` method, although I haven't found a reference in the Django documentation.

Is there a way to get the updated list at `save()` time? If not, is there a method I can overload to handle the list update within the Model definition?

(**Note**: Alternatives are also welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question regarding the m2m behavior :

[Django: accessing ManyToManyField objects after the save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197747/django-accessing-manytomanyfield-objects-after-the-save)

The reason you're not getting the updated data at the time save() is called is because Django handles the many to many relation changes later, and it can be accessed via the [m2m_changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

Hope this helps,

Regards