# Django - custom model save method doesn't show attributes values

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, overriding

while trying to save an instance of a model, I can't access the attributes values in the custom save() method. I think it should be possible straight forward, just like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) state. Here's what my code looks like:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    attribute1 = models.ManyToManyField("app.ModelName2", related_name="model_name_2")
    attribute2 = models.ForeignKey("app.ModelName3", related_name="model_name_3")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        print(self.attribute1.all()) # <---- it prints an empty qs, but in reality there are instances passed to attribute1 field.
```

Does anyone have any idea why that would happen? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something super obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those instances are added _after_ save is called as your model instance needs to have a pk before such related instances are added because m2ms are stored in an extra _intermediate_ database table.

Comment: Ok, that seems like an issue here, can you tell me what would be the proper way to go if I want to for example create other models based on ModelName.attribute1 values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: accessing ManyToManyField objects after the save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197747/django-accessing-manytomanyfield-objects-after-the-save)

Comment: Unfortunately not, when using models.signals.m2m_changed in the receiver, the function isn't even being called, whereas when using models.signals.post_save, it is called 2 times and both have an empty queryset :(

Comment: UPDATE: m2m_changed needed the sender to be set like ModelName.attribute1.through, while I was trying to have it set only to ModelName. Now I can access the qs properly! Thanks for your help, can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posting an answer would be counterintuitive to me marking it as a duplicate wouldn't it? You would have gotten some feedback about your question potentially being answered somewhere else, please accept that. :)

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Which App Inside Create This Model,You Have To Install App In setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '<your_app_name>'
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<app_name>.<model_name>
```

'

Comment: Thanks but that's not a problem at all, the app is present in INSTALLED_APPS.